# Conda env create from .yml gives "unexpected error"

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, environment

I've freshly reinstalled anaconda (python 3.7), and am trying to load an environment from a .yml I made previously. However, every .yml I try gives an unknown error...

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

produces:

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\cli\main.py", line 80, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\cli\main_create.py", line 80, in execute
        directory=os.getcwd())
      File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\specs\__init__.py", line 40, in detect
        if spec.can_handle():
      File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\specs\yaml_file.py", line 18, in can_handle
        self._environment = env.from_file(self.filename)
      File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\env.py", line 151, in from_file
        return from_yaml(yamlstr, filename=filename)
      File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\env.py", line 136, in from_yaml
        data = yaml_load_standard(yamlstr)
      File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\serialize.py", line 76, in yaml_load_standard
        return yaml.load(string, Loader=yaml.Loader, version="1.2")
      File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\main.py", line 638, in load
        loader = Loader(stream, version, preserve_quotes=preserve_quotes)
      File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\loader.py", line 46, in __init__
        Reader.__init__(self, stream, loader=self)
      File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\reader.py", line 80, in __init__
        self.stream = stream  # type: Any  # as .read is called
      File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\reader.py", line 112, in stream
        self.check_printable(val)
      File "C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\reader.py", line 233, in check_printable
        'unicode', "special characters are not allowed")
    ruamel_yaml.reader.ReaderError: unacceptable character #x0000: special characters are not allowed
      in "<unicode string>", position 3

`$ C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-env-script.py create -f environment.yml`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
  CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA=false
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_EXES="C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3
           CONDA_PREFIX_1=C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3
           CONDA_PREFIX_2=C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\envs\impala
           CONDA_PREFIX_3=C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\envs\fast
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\python.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=4
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\Myname
                     PATH=C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda
                          3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\Library\us
                          r\bin;C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Sebasti
                          an.Fuller\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\bin;C:
                          \Users\Myname\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\
                          Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\Library\usr\
                          bin;C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Sebastian
                          .Fuller\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\bin;C:\U
                          sers\Myname\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
                          Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\iCLS;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\iCLS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WI
                          NDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WIND
                          OWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
                          Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
                          Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
                          Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
                          Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps
                          Sync;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Migration;C:\Program
                          Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramD
                          ata\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\
                          Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\Programs
                          \Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\GitHubD
                          esktop\bin;C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\Box\Box
                          Edit;C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-pa
                          ckages\pywin32_system32;C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\Pyth
                          on\Python37\site-packages\pywin32_system32;C:\Users\Myname\A
                          ppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pywin32_system32;C:\Users
                          \Myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pywin3
                          2_system32;C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\s
                          ite-packages\pywin32_system32;C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roamin
                          g\Python\Python37\site-packages\pywin32_system32;C:\Users\Sebastian.Fu
                          ller\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pywin32_system32
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3
            shell level : 4
       user config file : C:\Users\Myname\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Myname\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Myname\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\Myname\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Myname\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.2 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

I know the environment is functional as it was working before I uninstalled conda! Any advice at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After some more investigation, the problem is the encoding of the file! Changing the encoding to UTF-8 using Save As in notepad fixed it.

Full thread I got the answer from here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7810